# Empty space above tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have got tableLayoutPanel with two columns and I dynamically add multiple rows. Everything works fine, but after application starts lots of empty space appears above first row.

There is image how its look like: [image]

There is my code related to tableLayoutPanel:

```
 //table layout settings
    accountsTable.ColumnCount = 2;
    accountsTable.Autoscroll = true;
    accountsTable.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
    accountsTable.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
    accountsTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    accountsTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
```

And dynamic adding new rows:

```
private void CreateAccountViews(int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                accountsTable.RowCount++;
            AccountView acView = new AccountView();
            acView.Name = "acView" + i.ToString();
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                accountsTable.Controls.Add(acView, 0, accountsTable.RowCount - 1);
            else
                accountsTable.Controls.Add(acView, 1, accountsTable.RowCount - 1);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me you keep adding controlls on the same row but increasing rowcount, not sure if that's the cause but it seems weird.

Comment: I can see that now. I have got two empty rows at the beginning of tableLayout. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you worked it out

Comment: The designer starts out by giving the TLP two rows.  Meant to be helpful and let you add controls to it at design-time.  But if you do it in code then you should remove them.